# Google Colab can't open many files

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

May 2023

Suddenly, Google Colab cannot open many files from gdrive. Gets stuck, just hangs, after opening less than 38 files.  You have to disconnect and delete the runtime and start over.

Minimal example (PIL has the same issue as cv2)

```
import os
from google.colab import drive
force_setup = False
drive.mount('/content/drive')
MOUNTED_PATH = Path('/content/drive')
MYDRIVE_PATH = MOUNTED_PATH / "MyDrive"

from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2
import glob

# use a folder with many files:
input_folder = "" #@param {type:"string"}
input_path = MYDRIVE_PATH / input_folder 

image_files = [str(f)
              for f in map(Path, sorted(glob.glob(f"{input_path}/*"))) 
              if f.is_file() and f.suffix in [".png"]
              ]
print(f"found {len(image_files)}")

# stops at 20
for file in tqdm(image_files):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
```

Output.  Just hangs here.

```
found 1968
  1%|          | 20/1968 [00:13<19:40,  1.65it/s]
```

Comment: Maybe file a complaint to google?

Comment: I emailed colab-help@google.com.

Comment: Issues like this should go to the colab github.  https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3651